# How to retrieve the corresponding data from a row in a gridview control when checking a checkbox added as a Template field

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I am a beginner in ASP.NET and I am not a code genius. I am hoping someone can help.

So I created a web form and added a gridview control to it. The gridview contains Two columns: Name_EN(the name of the subject), Select Subjects(a template column that contains a checkbox).

Ultimately I want a student to use this web form to register his subjects.
So whenever he clicks a submit button, he will be registered in all the subjects that he has selected using the checkbox.

I thought I could test this with adding a button that will print -on the web form- the Names of the subjects that I select.

This is the HTML and CSS code for the GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvUsers" runat="server" 
    CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" GridLines="None" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="source1" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name_EN" HeaderText="Name_EN" SortExpression="Name_EN" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select Subjects">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name_EN", "{0}") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>  
    </Columns>
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="cursor-pointer" />
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="source1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BIS1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="spViewAvailableSubjects" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="ID" SessionField="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then I need to view all the selected data from the "Name_EN" column but only for the rows where I checked the checkboxes when I click this Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="ViewButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="View Selected Subjects" OnClick="ViewButton_Click"/>
```

I am thinking to print the data using the Response.Write(); method.

But I am still a beginner with ASP.NET and I don't know how to implement that in code or how to connect the checkboxes with their corresponding data in the row.

I just want to retrieve the data and print them.

Can anyone help me with that?

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Registration Page.aspx.cs" Inherits="IntegratedSystems.Registration_Page" MasterPageFile="Site1.Master" %>

  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <%-- <form draggable="true" runat="server" style="max-width: 230px; text-align: left;">--%>
          <ul style="max-width: 230px; text-align: left;" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li class="text-left">
              <asp:Hyperlink ID="HomeLink" runat="server" CssClass="btn  " NavigateUrl="~/Student's Portal.aspx">Home</asp:Hyperlink>
            </li>
            <li class="text-left">
              <asp:HyperLink ID="InstructorLink" runat="server" CssClass="btn  ">Choose Instructors</asp:HyperLink>
            </li>
            <li class="text-left">
              <asp:HyperLink ID="TimeLink" runat="server" CssClass="btn  ">Choose Time</asp:HyperLink>
            </li>
            <li class="text-left">
              <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="HomeBtn_Click" CssClass="btn ">Logout</asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <br/>
          <label class="label label-info">These are the Available Subjects for your Registration</label>
          <asp:GridView ID="dgvUsers" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="source1">
            <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Name_EN" HeaderText="Name_EN" SortExpression="Name_EN" />
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select Subjects">
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name_EN", "{0}") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <RowStyle CssClass="cursor-pointer" />
          </asp:GridView>

          <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" GridLines="None" runat="server">

          </asp:GridView>

          <asp:SqlDataSource ID="source1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BIS1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="spViewAvailableSubjects" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <SelectParameters>
              <asp:SessionParameter Name="ID" SessionField="ID" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
          </asp:SqlDataSource>

          <br/>
          <asp:Button ID="ViewButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="View Selected Subjects" OnClick="ViewButton_Click" />

          <%--</form>--%>

      </div>
      
    </div>

  </asp:Content>
```

And here is the code behind file for the ViewButton click event:

```
protected void ViewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<string> selectedSubjects = new List<string>();
        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in dgvUsers.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) gvr.Cells[1].FindControl("CheckBox1");
            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                selectedSubjects.Add(chk.Text);

            }
        }

        if (selectedSubjects.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = selectedSubjects;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate through your gridview:

```
protected void ViewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    List<string> selectedSubjects = new List <string> ();
    foreach(GridViewRow gvr in dgvUsers.Rows) {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) gvr.Cells[1].FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (chk.Checked) {
            selectedSubjects.Add(chk.Text);
        }
    }

    if (selectedSubjects.Count > 0) {
        gvSelected.DataSource = selectedSubjects;
        gvSelected.DataBind();
    }
}
```

To display message to the user, add another gridview to the form:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSelected" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

Obviously, pretty it up as much as you can.

I personally, would not advise using Response.Write in web forms; the whole  point of them is to bind controls to code behind, not imitate classic asp.

Comment: I tried your solution but unfortunately the second GridView doesn't appear after I click the button. I really don't know what could have caused that.

Comment: Did you select any checkboxes? What happens if you put a breakpoint on button click function and step through? Do you get any items added to the list?

Comment: Yes, I did check all the checkboxes. But the strange thing is that when I debug the ViewButton() code, when iterating through the foreach loop, it shows me that the checkbox is not checked. Please note that I repeated this process many times and I assure you, I check the checkboxes.

Comment: Could you re-post exactly your ASPX source, as well as ViewButton click event source here. I'll try to emulate the error.

Comment: Do you have a master page with that? That could be an issue.

Comment: well, yes. I do have a Master page associated with this page. But I don't really see how this can be an issue.

Comment: Master pages change control names, so code behind might not be recognizing the check box.

Comment: OK, but I also tried removing the Master Page and still got the same result.

Comment: Besides, isn't there any way to know what the master page changed the control name to?. Please note that I have edited the post and added the full source of the web form as you requested and also the source code behind the ViewButton_Click event/

Comment: I have found the issue. It was an issue with a line of code that I wrote in the Page_load event. Here it is:    try
            {
                dgvUsers.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
                dgvUsers.DataBind();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.ToString());
            }

Comment: The Issue was immediately fixed after I removed that line. I just don't know what kind of effect did it have on the iteration through the gridview.

Comment: Glad it's resolved. :)   Although the code in page load is not necessary, it binds the gridview before there is any data. If you must have it, check for control being databound first,             if(dgvUsers.DataSource != null)
            { 
            try
            {
                    dgvUsers.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
                    dgvUsers.DataBind();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { Response.Write(ex.ToString()); }
            }